# How to convert friction to damping ratio for a spring animation system

Tags: calculus

Suppose the *tension* is 381 and *friction* is 20, what are their corresponding **stiffness** and **damping ratio** value?

[image]

Comment: You mean there's a constant force of $20_N$ applied opposite to the direction of movement?

Comment: @Soroushkhoubyarian I added a screenshot taken from Principle for mac app.

Comment: @user3663635 hey, did you found the answer?